# Would blocking off the heater matrix hoses cause overheating?

Tags: overheating, heater-blower, leyland-sherpa

I have an austin morris sherpa 230 petrol with an "o" series engine. I believe the heater matrix always dissipates some heat and only warms the cab when a slider is opetated releasing a flap cover to direct heat into the van.You can also switch on a fan to this matrix.
I want to block off the heater hoses to the matrix. How dependent do you think the cooling system generally is on this heater circuit and would blocking it off cause overheating?
The reason i want to do this is because my new other engine is overheating i presume because i have introduced a contraflow in the system by hooking up the old heater hoses to the new engine which although is an o series engine came with its spigots in different positions. I presume this is because the engine is also used in the morris marina,princess etc which i suppose has a different cooling system arrangement. This would be a temporary arrangement untill i have an engineer install a new spigot in the head.

Answer (score 2):

I am not at all familiar with the vehicle in question, however  you may want to consider looping the coolant flow rather than blocking it off. Install a hose from the engine heater core inlet to the engine outlet . This will simulate the natural flow and reduce the risk of air pockets  which can cause overheating issues.

Answer (score 0):

No, blocking of the heater matrix will not cause overheating.

How often do you need heat in summer? The rest of the cooling system keeps it cool.

However I have, in the past, used the heater to help cool an engine so it did not overheat when towing hard for example.

Comment: no i don't need heater in summer. Please can you clarify. Are yo saying that the heater matrix plays no part or a negligible part in the the cooling system generally. It's  just that the matrix seems to be giving of heat whether the flaps are down and heater fan off - or not!

Comment: no i don't need heater in summer. Please can you clarify. Are yo saying that the heater matrix plays no part or a negligible part in the the cooling system generally. It's just that the matrix seems to be giving of heat whether the flaps are down and heater fan off - or not! –

Comment: @mikes really appreciate this comment even though i was planning to do that anyway..nicely explained too.

Comment: @mikes actually ive just realised that if i loop the heater matrix hoses then the faulty arrangement i have currently will still be there. My only option is to block off the hoses to  stop what i believe is a contraflow. Hopefully that wont interfere too much with the coolung system as it was designed to be.